# How to change pH of CuSO4?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, ph, uv-vis-spectroscopy, buffer

I'm currently very desperate to know this. I'm doing an experiment about adsorption/chelation of Cu ions in CuSO4 using banana peels using the UV-Visible spectroscopy. How do I change the pH of 0.1M or 0.05M of CuSO4? My main problem is with making the CuSO4 more alkaline/basic or whatever u call it. My base pH of the CuSO4 is about 4.0 or 4.1. I've tried making a pH 5 and pH 6 buffer solution then adding it to the CuSO4 solution, but so far it's only made it more acidic.
These are the calculations:

pH 5

Weigh 5.10575g of potassium hydrogen phthalate(C8H5KO4)

Dissolve it in a 100cm3 beaker

Transfer the solution into a 250cm3 volumetric flask and fill it with distilled water

Measure 5cm3 of 2M NaOH and add it to a 100cm3 volumetric flask and fill it with distilled water

Add 100cm3 of 0.1M potassium hydrogen phthalate and 45.2cm3 of 0.1M NaOH into a 250cm3 beaker

pH 6

Weigh 3.40225g of KH2PO4

Dissolve it in a 100cm3 beaker

Transfer the solution into a 250cm3 volumetric flask and fill it with distilled water

Measure 5cm3 of 2M NaOH and add it to a 100cm3 volumetric flask and fill it with distilled water

Add 100cm3 of 0.1M KH2PO4 and 11.2cm3 of 0.1M NaOH

But I realised the phosphate buffers will cause a precipitate. So I tried using a citric acid + sodium citrate buffer. I think the calculation was something like 88.5cm^3 of citric acid + 11.5 cm^3 of sodium citrate (or it could be the other way around). But I don't think that was a buffer solution, cus when I added the slightest amount of deionized water, the pH increased. I got it from https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/life-science/core-bioreagents/biological-buffers/learning-center/buffer-reference-center.html#citric2.

Someone please help this is experiment is basically graded, so I'm really desperate.

edit: I made the copper sulfate using CuSO4.5H2O if that helps

Comment: Copper(II) phosphate is insoluble in water. You could try acetic acid/acetate (pKa = 4.76). pH 6 is very close to neutral i would rather avoid it.

Comment: Also this could be useful for you. http://microscopy.berkeley.edu/Resources/instruction/buffers.html

Comment: Your major problem is you are using way too high concentration of your $\ce{Cu^2+}$ solution. The maximum concentration of solutions used in the given article is $\pu{0.00787 M}$.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, your problem has no solution, because of the risk of producing $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ at pH $5$ and $6$. The solubility product of $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ is $2.2·10^{-20}$. At pH $5$ and $6$, the concentrations of the ion $\ce{OH-}$ are respectively $10^{-9}$ and $10^{-8}$ M. This means that, at pH $5$ and $6$, the maximum molar concentrations of the ion $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ are $2.2·10^{-2}$ M and $2.2·10^{-4}$ M respectively. So you will never be able to obtain a $0.1$ M solution of $\ce{CuSO4}$ at pH $5$ or $6$.

Comment: how about 0.05M?

Comment: For 0.05 M, it is the same. 0.05 M is greater than the limit of 0.022 M.

Comment: I saw one article or paper that said they did it up till pH 6 then after that they got precipitate. <https://www.geomatejournal.com/sites/default/files/articles/227-234-3c-anwar%20hossain.pdf>

Comment: also, do u know what's the highest pH I can get for the solution then?

Comment: one more thing, can u think of any reason y my pH 6 buffer made the CuSO4 more acidic?

Comment: No. I don't know the maximum value of the pH for copper sulfate solutions. The problem is that, if you want to make precise calculations, you have to use activities and not concentrations. All my previous calculations are made with concentrations. They are probably a little wrong. As you know, insoluble products are always more soluble than the values obtained from the solubility product, specially with substances producing doubly charged ions like $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$.

Comment: Sorry. I cannot tell you the reason why a buffer does not give its pH value, without knowing the composition of this buffer.

Comment: It was citric acid and sodium citrate. Both at 0.1M

Comment: Citric acid is a weak acid. Lets call it $\ce{H3X}$. In aqueous solution, it doe not produce many ions $\ce{H+}$. But in presence of copper ions $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ it reacts producing a complex $\ce{CuX^-}$ and $3$ ions $\ce{H+}$. Three ! It becomes a strong acid. The equation is $$\ce{Cu^{2+} + H3X -> CuX^- + 3 H+}$$

Comment: ohhh nice. no wonder my solution became acidic